# Can I change my user profile using the API?

Tags: support

It seems the API just allow me to retrive public information, but... is it possible to change, for instance, my "about_me" information using the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

[Version 1](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/) of the API is read only.