# Can I change my profile picture using the API version 2?

Tags: feature-request, api, users, api-v2.2, images

I was considering making an app that lets the user design a profile picture and then activate it on the user's Stack Exchange account. Could a feature to change the profile picture be added to the write API?

[The list of APIs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) shows `/users/{ids}` and `/me`, which return a [`user` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) containing a `profile_image` field. But it doesn't show anything for *writing* to paths in `/users/`. Otherwise, the user will have to download the image and then go digging for it in the file system in order to upload it using a web browser. Or is inability to change the profile picture one of the "constraints imposed to prevent abuse" mentioned in [Write Access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write)?

The closest question I found was [Can I change my user profile using the API?](https://stackapps.com/q/677/37310). Its answer merely pointed out that version 1 of the API was read-only.

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, you cannot do this with the current API.
See, and upvote, this related feature request: [Is there an API to upload images to SE's imgur installation?](https://stackapps.com/questions/2664/is-there-an-api-to-upload-images-to-ses-imgur-installation)

See, also, [Using the Stack Exchange API to update my user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254250/using-the-stack-exchange-api-to-update-my-user-profile) on Meta Stack Exchange.

**Your only current possibility is to manipulate the user's normal profile page, if you can.**

---

I doubt that this feature is blocked by "constraints imposed to prevent abuse".  It is more likely demand (low) versus difficulty (medium to high).